# Handling duplicate username error on PFUser currentUser cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, authentication, parse-platform

I can't find the proper solution to this problem. In the app I am creating, I allow users to change their username whenever they wish. So I do the following when they go to the settings page and update their info:

```
PFUser *modifiedCurrent = [PFUser currentUser];
[modifiedCurrent setObject:username.text forKey:@"username"];
[modifiedCurrent setObject:name.text forKey:@"additional"];
[modifiedCurrent setObject:email.text forKey:@"email"];
[modifiedCurrent saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Error"
                              message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[error userInfo]  
                              objectForKey:@"error"]]
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
}];
```

The server would obviously return an error if the user has chosen a username already in use and thus won't update the database. HOWEVER, the cached version of [PFUser currentUser] seems to update the username field regardless of whether there was an error or not. How do I prevent this from happening? Or how do I revert to the previous "legitimate" username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would query to see if the user with that username existed before attempting the change. I'm actually surprised that an error is actually registering on the collision.

Otherwise, you could call fetch on the user object.

Comment: I thought of querying users with that username but didn't want to eat into my API usage. However, I just decided to do it this way anyway granted that people shouldn't be changing usernames too often.

Comment: Yeah probably safer. I've had a lot of trouble with the user object being in stale states. Only really happens during testing because of changing data in the backend...

Comment: You know, ultimately you'd have to consider to do it with some server code: conceivably you could query if new username XYZ existed, and then while you are getting ready to save that username, some other person could create a user with that name! Generally Parse is not setup to handle locks, etc. You're quite right Pork, it's annoying when PFUser data goes stale during development, you delete a user on the server but it still sort of works locally, heh!